# Confusion of a formula about Lagrangian

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, quadratic-forms

Recently, I am reading a [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.454.9868) about eigenvalue problems. Consider the following problem, which occurs at the first page of the paper.

\begin{align}
\text{minimize}\quad &x^TAx \\
\text{subject to}\quad & x^Tx = 1 \\
& c^Tx = 0 \tag{$\bigstar$}
\end{align}
where $A$ is a real symmetric matrix and in addition, $c^Tc = 1$. Its corresponding Lagrangian can be written as
$$
L(x, \lambda, \mu) = x^TAx - \lambda\cdot(x^Tx - 1) + 2\mu \cdot c^Tx
$$
Letting its first derivative equal to $0$, we have
$$
Ax - \lambda\cdot x + \mu \cdot c = 0
$$
Multiplying the LHS of the equation by $c^T$ and using the fact $c^Tc = 1$, I obtain
$$
\mu = -c^TAx + \color{red}{\lambda\cdot c^Tx} \tag{$\spadesuit$}
$$
But as shown in the second page of the paper, the paper obtains
$$
\mu = -c^TAx \tag{$\clubsuit$}
$$
If I understand correctly, it uses the constraint $c^Tx = 0$ ($\bigstar$). Why can the constraint be used here when minimizing the Lagrangian? Should not Lagrangian functions be minimized over the domain of $x$ rather than the feasible region to obtain the dual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $x$ in the Lagrangian can be any value. However the "subject to" constraints tell us that the domain over which you are to minimize $L$ are only those that satisfy $c^Tx = 0$ and $x^Tx = 1$, i.e. all $x$ in the intersection of the unit $n$-sphere and the plane $c^Tx = 0$. After you have derived the Lagrangian equations

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mu} = 2c^Tx = 0,~~~\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda} = 1 - x^Tx = 0,~~~\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = 2(Ax - \lambda x + \mu c) = 0$$

you are now free to use $c^Tx = 0$ (the first equation) to simplify the other equations as you are looking for a solution that satisfy all of these equations at the same time. The only thing you cannot do is to apply them in the Lagrangian itself before deriving the Lagrangian equations.

Comment: @NP-hard Read the last paragraph. You can only do this after deriving the Lagrangian equations. After deriving the Lagrangian equation you are left with just a normal equation system to solve and you are free to use standard methods like using one equation in the others.

Comment: @NP-hard The Lagrangian itself is a function over all $x,\mu,\lambda$ - not just those in the domain you are interested in so you cannot assume $c^Tx = 0$ at the Lagrangian level. However when you minimize $L$ you are interested in finding the stationary points of $L$. These are dictated by the Lagrangian equations (and the contraints like $c^Tx = 0$ are "baked into" these). After you have derived these equations you are just solving a standard  equation system, one equation of which is $c^Tx = 0$, so you are free to use it at this level.

Comment: @NP-hard Wait, when did the dual enter it to this?

Comment: OK I see you edited the question after I answered.

Comment: You should edit it to make it more clear what you are asking for. What you have written does not seem to have much to do with finding the dual, it looks like you are just asking about using a constraint in finding the minimum. I don't have access to the paper so I can't do that.

Comment: @NP-hard I looked at the paper but I still don't understand. Why do you suddenly want to compute the Lagrangian dual for solving the problem at hand? Where does this come in? It's nothing about this mentioned in the paper as far as I can see.

Comment: Yours is correct. Thanks a lot. I have misunderstood the paper because when I saw the optimization problem, the method of Lagrangian dual came to my mind immediately and I didn't notice that it is just an optimization problem with equality constraints. Stupid of me and a stupid question. Thanks again.